# CSS if/else statement for counting list items

Tags: css, if-statement

I need an if/else statement for my CSS which can count list items.  Would this be possible?

Basically I want to say, if there are less than 10 list items, the UL container should be 200px wide, and it there are more than 10 list items, it should be 400px wide.  Something like that.

Can it be done?

I would appreciate a working demo on jsFiddle, both so I can see working code, and for anyone who looks here in the future so they can see a working example and how to do it :)

Comment: There may be a css solution for this, but it depends on what your intention is for those list-items. Do the list items themselves get wider? Do they float next to each other? What is the desired behavior of the li's if the list get's wider?

Comment: I just ended up posting an answer assuming merely a `width` change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS only does styles, but not dynamically (unless with assistance of JS). you can use [the following JS snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/bt3KK/2/) for the task. just to make sure, load this at the very last, just before the `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function resize() { 

    //get all lists with selected name
    var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('myList');

    //loop through all gathered lists
    for (i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {

        //shorthand elements for easy use
        var list = lists[i];
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

        //append class names
        list.className = (items.length < 10) ? 'myList less' : 'myList more';
    }
}())​

</script>

.less{
    width:200px;
}
.more{
    width:400px;
}​
```

Comment: I tried this but couldnt get it working.  Can you post a demo on jsFiddle?

Comment: Is it possible to make it modify the ul.myList width rather than the list items themselves?  I would like the list items to always be 200px wide.  But when the UL container goes to 400px width, it would display the list items side by side in 2 columns of 200px.  I tried to modify the code myself, but couldnt get it to work quite right

Answer (score 1):

CSS has no `if else` statements. You can do this easily with jQuery. Another option would be to use LESS or SCSS.

Comment: If LESS/SCSS could do it, so could CSS, because that's what those two are compiled into. Unless you use one of those JS implementations which could potentially have something like this, but I haven't heard of any and they aren't really meant for production use anyways.

Comment: Well, yeah, in this case you probably need JS. This is more as general solution to dynamic css. SCSS can do `if else` an LESS can do JS evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. CSS offers no conditional support.

Long answer: you need to use javascript or a server side language to either add a class when there are more than 10 items (or elements) in the list, or in the case of javascript, directly manipulate the style after it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound possible for CSS. There are no logical if/else statements in the CSS spec. Your next best bet would probably be javascript. You could achieve this with jQuery with the following code:

```
if($('ul#target-list li').length < 10) {
    $('ul#target-list').css('width', 200);
}
else {
    $('ul#target-list').css('width', 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure CSS3 Solution

If you only want to support CSS3, then this does what you need:

```
li {
   width: 200px;
}

li:nth-last-child(n+11),
li:nth-last-child(n+11) ~ li {
   width: 400px;
}
```

But you will need to make the `ul` either [`display: inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/nE7hT/8/) or [`float`](http://jsfiddle.net/nE7hT/10/) it so that the width is controlled by the `li` elements themselves. This may require you to wrap the [`ul` (`display: inline-block`) in a `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/nE7hT/14/) so that it still is a block element in the flow of the page if you need it so.